# Tensorflow optimiser.compute_gradients runs way slower on the first step

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, multi-gpu

I have a complex *rnn* model written in tensorflow for *multigpu* training. When I run my *tf* code, the graph building happens in reasonable time.

But, when I call `sess.run` to run the graph, the optimiser.compute_gradients takes a lot of time to run for the first step, but gets much faster(around 10X faster) for the subsequent steps. Every batch in my *dataset* are of the same shape.

Why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: Did you benchmark the data loading? How do you feed the data into your graph? [mcve]?